# Bug in my NASM program

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

So I'm going to qualify this by saying that I'm new to NASM and I'm reading the http://www.drpaulcarter.com/pcasm/ assembly tutorial.

I'm compiling in Linux (Ubuntu) using 32bit 80x86 as my instruction set (I think...).

The purpose of my program is to trim any unnecessary space from a string that's read in. So all spaces at the start of the string, and any double or greater spaces between a word.

My program is almost finished with a single undocumented feature that's bothering me. If I have a word with two trailing spaces and a word with one trailing space, my program will eat the single trailing space of the second word. But this bug doesn't generally happen, only the first instance of a two space one space line up.

Here's my make file:

```
mstrebl  : asm_io.inc  asm_io.o driver.o mstrebl.o
    gcc -o mstrebl -m32 asm_io.o driver.o mstrebl.o

driver.o : driver.c
    gcc -c driver.c -m32

mstrebl.o: mstrebl.asm
    nasm -f elf32 mstrebl.asm
```

and this is the C program that calls ASM_MAIN in all of the tutorial programs

```
int main()
{
  int ret_status;
  ret_status = asm_main();
  return ret_status;
}
```

Here is my ASM file.

```
%include "asm_io.inc"

LF  equ 0Ah

segment .data

name_prompt    DB  'Please enter a string to be trimmed: ',0
out_msg        DB  'The trimmed string is: ',0

segment .bss

in_name    resb  80

segment .text
        global  asm_main
asm_main:
        enter   0,0            ; setup routine
        pusha
restart:

    mov  eax, name_prompt  ; print prompt
    call print_string
    mov  ebx, in_name
                       ;for counting the number of digits
rd_loop:

    call read_char         ; read in the string
    mov  [ebx], al
        inc  ebx
    cmp  al, LF
        jne  rd_loop

    dec  ebx               ; put in null terminator
    mov  byte [ebx], 0
        call print_nl          ; print output msg
        mov  eax, out_msg
    call print_string
        mov  ebx, in_name      ; EBX := address of in_name   

    push in_name
    call strebl             ;this pushes the string onto EAX, destroying old data.

    call print_string 
    add esp, 4

Finished:

        call print_nl
        call print_nl

        popa
        mov     eax, 0         ; return back to C
        leave                     
        ret

; subprogram get_int
; Parameters (in order pushed on stack)
;
;Address of the first character in a string (at [ebp + 8])
; Notes:
; There are no data shifts on the stack, only for the address
; of the array, as such, esp is not changed or shifted.
;
; Note, this destroys the contents of EAX.
; Note, this destroys the contents of CL.


;SUDO CODE!
;j = first address of the string
;if(*char == '\0')
;   return *char
;while((*char + i) == ' ')
;   i += 1 
; 
;
;while((*char + i != ' '))
;{
;   if((*char + i) == '\0')
;       return *char
;
;   (*char + j) = (*char + i)
;   j += 1;
;}
;
;jump to original while

segment .data

temp   db 0

segment .text
 strebl:
    push EBP
    mov  EBP, ESP
    mov  EAX, [EBP + 8] ; I
    mov  EBP, [EAX]     ; J

 First_while:

    cmp byte [EAX], 0
    je  End_strebl
    cmp byte[EAX], ' ' ;or 32 if i need to change it
    jne Second_While

    inc EAX ; i
    jmp First_while

 Second_While:

    cmp byte [EAX], 0
    je  End_strebl    

    cmp byte[EAX], ' '
    je  Second_While_helper

    ;*EBX = *EAX
    mov ECX, [EAX]
    mov [EBX], ECX

    inc EAX ; increment I and J at the same time 
    inc EBX

    jmp Second_While

Second_While_helper:

    inc EAX
    inc EBX

helper_loop:

    cmp byte[EAX], ' '
    jne Second_While

    inc EAX

    jmp helper_loop

End_strebl:
    cmp EAX, EBX
    jz  done_strebl
    mov byte[EBX], ' '

done_strebl:

    mov EAX, [ESP + 8]
    pop EBP
    ret
```

Comment: "mov  EBP, [EAX]     ; J" is that what you intended? EBP doesn't appear to be referenced anywhere again.

Comment: EBP is referenced  at
  ;*EBX = *EAX
    mov ECX, [EAX]
    mov [EBX], ECX

and 

inc EBX twice

Comment: I derped that one up pretty good. I saw EBX instead of EBP. And I wrote to random address space. You even spelled it out for me. Ahhhhhh, I feel so stupid now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

500- internal server Error pointed out my error in a comment above.